# The relationship between pdf and cdf of a continuous random variable

Tags: probability, distributions

> If the pdf(probability density function) of Y is continuous, it can be obtained by differentiating the cdf(cumulative distribution function).
>   --"Statistical Inference"

My question is: when the pdf of Y is not continuous, can't we obtain the pdf by differentiating the cdf?

Comment: If the pdf exists at all--no matter what properties it might have--then *by definition* it is the derivative of the cdf (provided one understands that the pdf represents a density and not a function).

Answer (score 1):

Yes! The density of a continuous distribution is the derivative of the CDF.$^{\dagger}$

**Example**: the uniform distribution, say on $(0,1)$, which has PDF $f(x)=   \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      1 & x\in (0,1)\\
      0 & x\notin (0,1) \\
\end{array} 
\right.$.

Then the CDF is $F(x)=   \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      0& x\le0\\
      x & x\in (0,1)\\
      1 & x\ge0) \\
\end{array} 
\right.$.

You can see that $\dfrac{dF(x)}{dx} = f(x)$, as you'd expect.

We don't usually talk about the PDF as being continuous, however. Continuous vs discrete concerns the CDF. Fair warning: the details of this quickly get you into heavy real analysis, including measure theory.

$^{\dagger}$In some sense, you *always* can get the density through a derivative. Measure theory unifies discrete, continuous, and even funkier distributions and gives their densities through something called the Radon-Nikodym derivative.

Comment: Re "you can see that:" unless you take more care defining what you mean by the derivative, your assertion is incorrect when $x=0$ or $x=1,$ because (according to elementary definitions of the derivative) $F$ is not differentiable at either of those points.